# How do i make my Audio loop in my website?

Tags: audio, streaming

Here is my code:

`<div id="div6" style="position: absolute; top: 700px; left: 100px;">
<audio controls="controls; loop:true">
  <source src="../media/ChealseSmile.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>`

What do i have to add to the audio code to make it loop or autostart?

As a bonus, could someone also tell me how to make a playlist out of this code?

Comment: You don't ... It's impossible ... (*sigh*, okay, I'm joking, but I wish I wasn't).

Comment: Please don't!  Really, I'm not joking - your site will be condidered annoying (at best)

Answer (score 2):

```
<audio loop="loop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio loop id="music" controls autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="music.oog" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   <embed height="2" width="2" src="engine1/granadosorienta_pianol.mp3">
</audio>
```

Then you can add this JS for old FF browsers if you want to support them

```
<!--- Fix the FF Audio Loop bug --!>
  document.getElementById('music').addEventListener('ended', function(){
  this.currentTime = 0;
  this.play();
}, false);
```